# What's the best way to create space in latex paragraphs

Tags: math-mode, spacing

The below puts a tab after "Let"; How can I prevent that tab from appearing? is bigbreak the best way to space this?

[image: computeitnegral]

```
Compute the integral:

\[
    \iint_{D} \pi \cos (\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{y-x}{y+x}) \, dx \, dy
\]
where $D$ is bounded by $(1,0), (2,0), (0,1), (0,2)$.

\bigbreak{}

Let
\[
    u = y-x,
    v = y+x
\]
```

Comment: the indentation is unrelated to the equation, it is a paragraph indent as you have started a new paragraph by adding a blank line in the source.

Comment: perhaps you are looking for `\usepackage{parskip}` so paragraphs are marked by vertical space and no indentation (like paragraphs on this web site)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. thanks. I'm not sure I understand why "Compute the integral" is a brand new paragraph, but this is not tabbed?  On another note I tried parkskip but I get "Missing number, treated as zero" right after \parskip.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle nevermind, It worked just had to use the package and not the keyword.  Can you put your comment as an answer? I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation is unrelated to the equation, it is a paragraph indent as you have started a new paragraph by adding a blank line in the source.

Perhaps you are looking for `\usepackage{parskip}` so paragraphs are marked by vertical space and no indentation (like paragraphs on this web site).